# How to compile a .NET winform to native code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core, native

i have 1 winform written in .net 7.0 is there any way to compile application to native code.

I have read many articles and tried many ways but it seems they do not support winform.

If possible, can you give me a detailed example.

Comment: If you are talking about NativeAOT, that only supports console applications in .NET7 (it will support more types in .NET8). Is there any particular reason you want to compile to native code instead of using something like a self-contained app?

Comment: There's a YouTube video that shows how to compile C# to native code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa3XsvSiMtk, by publishing instead of compiling/building regularly. Did you watch that and try the steps? Also, personally I'm not sure why would you need to compile C# programs to native code. To my knowledge, C# programs written with .NET Core can be compiled to native code, but I'm not sure why. I would personally rather use C/C++ or other language that compiles to native code in order to compile programs to native code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 7 supports Native AOT only for console apps. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows#limitations-in-the-net-native-aot-deployment-model):

> Native AOT is targeted towards console-type apps. Only a limited number of libraries are fully compatible with native AOT.

There are some community efforts you can try - for example [WinFormsComInterop](https://github.com/kant2002/winformscominterop#getting-started)

See also:

- [Epic - Make WinForms trim compatible](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/4649)
- [ComWrappers support](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/5163)
- [nativeAOT whether to support winform or wpf programs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79166)

Answer (score 0):

Publish native AOT using the CLI
Add true to your project file.

This property enables native AOT compilation during publish. It also enables dynamic code-usage analysis during build and editing. It's preferable to put this setting in the project file rather than passing it on the command line, since it controls behaviors outside publish.

XML

```
Copy
  <PropertyGroup>
      <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Publish the app for a specific runtime identifier using dotnet publish -r .

The following example publishes the app for Windows as a native AOT application on a machine with the required prerequisites installed.

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release
```

The following example publishes the app for Linux as a native AOT application. A native AOT binary produced on Linux machine is only going to work on same or newer Linux version. For example, native AOT binary produced on Ubuntu 20.04 is going to run on Ubuntu 20.04 and later, but it isn't going to run on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
dotnet publish -r linux-arm64 -c Release
```

The app is available in the publish directory and contains all the code needed to run in it, including a stripped-down version of the coreclr runtime.

Check out the native AOT samples available in the dotnet/samples repository on GitHub. The samples include Linux and Windows Dockerfiles that demonstrate how to automate installation of prerequisites and publish .NET projects with native AOT using containers.
[Publish native AOT using the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows#publish-native-aot-using-the-cli)

Comment: _"dotnet publish -r linux-arm64"_ - taking in account that OP is using Winforms that is a doubtfully useful information =)